# Can conjunctions be used to join prepositions with the same object?

Tags: classical-latin, preposition, word-usage

It is a characteristic of a certain kind of academic writing (or amateurish misconceptions thereof) to join prepositions by conjunctions with only one object. Some examples:

> The realization of the good of all **in and through** the act of each is the social ideal. (*Practical Ethics*, William DeWitt Hyde)

Or the common idiom: ["in and of itself"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in-and-of-itself).

**Are there any examples in classical literature of two prepositions being joined by a conjunction with the same object?**

Obviously, I am not interested in cases like "per ipsum, et cum ipso, et in ipso."

A word search for ["in et"](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23in+et%23) (with word boundaries) shows only result where "in" is treated as a noun, i.e. "the word *in*."

Comment: Interesting question! It might be useful to search a text corpus for patterns like "in X et per X" (with any two prepositions), where the X's are the same. If this is common, then one could argue that it is the idiomatic option for "in et per X". I lack the aptitude to make such searches.

Comment: The Vulgate is full of "in X et per X". Post-classical, though

Comment: Dubious: *DRN* 2.393: *aut quia ni mirum maioribus est elementis /
aut magis hamatis inter se perque plicatis*. This could be analysed as an adverb. I think the problem is that prepositions and adverbs are not entirely separate in Latin/Greek, and I think *in* in your example could be analysed as an adverb as well, if we should ignore traditional terminology for English momentarily and analyse it with the same lack of separation in mind.

Comment: *Aeneid* 4.671: *Karthago aut antiqua Tyros, flammaeque furentes / culmina perque hominum uoluantur perque deorum.* You might call this simple ellipsis, because only the head of the object of the two prepositions is absent after the second preposition—but, then, isn't what you're after really ellipsis of a prepositional object?

Comment: Cicero, *Rhet. Her.* [sp.], 4.68.16: *Id fieri poterit, si, quae ante et post et in ipsa re facta erunt, conprehendemus*. Here the same applies as in my quotation from Lucretius above.

Comment: Varro, *Res Rusticae*, 1.35.2.5: *dum in xv diebus ante et post brumam, ut pleraque, ne facias.* I think this one is incontrovertible [strange how we spell this word with a -t-, incidentally]. It seems necessary to interpret *ante* as *ante brumam*, or it wouldn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Cerberus Great examples. I'd accept an answer, especially with that last example.

Comment: @Cerberus 's Varro example is the only example of this phenomenon in the Oxford Latin Syntax, which calls it "very rarely attested": https://books.google.com/books?id=Y05zCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA891&lpg=PA891&dq=dum+in+xv+diebus+ante+et+post+brumam,+ut+pleraque,+ne+facias&source=bl&ots=hQojIWr8bz&sig=SskzFHNIN5PszmCDV7rwXRCtwws&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqwLy6jJjRAhUnwlQKHfhbA4kQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=dum%20in%20xv%20diebus%20ante%20et%20post%20brumam%2C%20ut%20pleraque%2C%20ne%20facias&f=false

Comment: @TKR: Interesting. What does the OLS call the phaenomenon? (I can't access it on Books.)

Comment: @Cerberus, it's not labeled -- just a paragraph at the end of the prepositions section (p. 1228).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *DRN* 2.393: *aut quia ni mirum maioribus est elementis /
>   aut magis hamatis **inter se perque** plicatis*.

This one is somewhat dubious. It could be analysed as an adverb. I think the problem is that prepositions and adverbs are not entirely separate in Latin/Greek, and I think *in* in your example could be analysed as an adverb as well, if we should ignore traditional terminology for English momentarily and analyse it with the same lack of separation in mind.

> *Aeneid* 4.671: *Karthago aut antiqua Tyros, flammaeque furentes / culmina **perque hominum uoluantur perque deorum**.*

You might call this simple ellipsis, because only the head of the object of the two prepositions is absent after the second preposition—but, then, isn't what you're after really ellipsis of a prepositional object?

> Cicero, *Rhet. Her.* [sp.], 4.68.16: *Id fieri poterit, si, quae **ante et post et in ipsa re** facta erunt, conprehendemus*.

Here the same applies as in my quotation from Lucretius above.

> Varro, *Res Rusticae*, 1.35.2.5: *dum in xv diebus **ante et post brumam**, ut pleraque, ne facias.*

I think this one is incontrovertible [strange how we spell this word with a -t-, incidentally]. It seems necessary to interpret *ante* as *ante brumam*, or it wouldn't make sense to me.